# datatable.fnDraw() is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a datatable which is being populated and displayed as I wish. There is a date column that I could like to apply a date range filter to. There are two controls on my HTML page that I have given id's to and added the datepicker jquery to . I've looked at the code example given here https://datatables.net/plug-ins/filtering/row-based/range_dates but when I run the code a and change the date on the control I see an error that `oTable.draw()` is not a function.

I'm using datatables 1.10.11 and I've set my table up using the following code

```
var statementTable = $('#statementTable').DataTable({....});
```

The on change event is being trigger with this line

```
$('#startdatepicker').change(function () { statementTable.fnDraw(); });
```

When this line executes I see the error in the console:

> statementTable.fnDraw() is not a function.

Can anyone offer any pointers please?
Thanks
Richard

Comment: What do you use `statementTable.fnDraw()` or `statementTable.draw()` ? Because the latter is what you should use

Comment: @PierreDuc I have tried it with both     fnDate() and     date() but get the same error message.

Comment: your `statementTable` is not a datatable. that's why the fdDraw() does not exist. do you initialize it correctly? maybe a value on the constructor is undefined?

Comment: @Sharky, the datatable displays the data correctly and the default functions for ordering and search are working.  The code for the table constructor is           ``function SetupStatementDataTable() {
            var statementTable = $('#statementTable').DataTable({
                "paging": false,
                "searching": true,
                "info": false,
                "scrollY": "450px",
                "sScrollX": "100%",
                "sScrollXInner": "110%",
                "asStripeClasses": [],
                responsive: true,
                select: true
            });``

Comment: Probably your var `statementTable`  isn't in the same environment. Show your js code for to help!!!

Comment: Thank you @CMedina, it was the declaration of the statementTable that was causing the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by the declaration of the statementTable being in the wrong place so not available to the wider context. See the comments below the original post.

Answer (score 13):

Method `fnDraw()` is older API method for DataTables 1.9.

For newer DataTables 1.10+ when you initialize table with `DataTable()`, use newer [`draw()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/draw%28%29) API method instead.

```
$('#startdatepicker').change(function () { statementTable.draw(); });
```

Alternatively you can initialize your table with `dataTable()`, then older API methods such as `fnDraw()` would still work.